# xcassets: A XXxXX app icon is required for iPhone apps targeting releases of iOS prior to 7.0

Tags: ios, icons, xcasset

When trying to handle all icons and images using xcassets I get warnings stating that 57x57, 57x57@2x, 72x72 and 72x72@2x icons are needed as I target iOS 5+ devices.

The problem is that:

- The default `AppIcon` group won't accept those icons.
- Adding separate entries for `Icon` and `Icon-72` won't fix the warnings neither.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Solved it by right clicking and choosing Editor > New App Icon.
This created a new AppIcon group with both iOS 6 and 7 icon placeholders.

The problem was due to Xcode templates where all new projects are iOS 7+ by default.

---

Also configurable by selecting the `AppIcon` image set and using the Attributes Inspector:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my app i have made group of icons and add icon with name bellow :

icon-29.png
icon-29@2x.png
icon-40.png
icon-40@2x.png
icon-72.png
icon-72@2x.png
icon-76.png
icon-76@2x.png
icon-120.png
icon.png(57x57)
icon@2x.png(114x114)

i am using Xcode 5